# How do I replace all occurences of a multiline string in another string?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to replace all occurences of a multiline string in another string. Assuming that **input** contains the input text, **output** contains the resulting text, **searchText** contains the multiline string to be found and **replaceText** contains the replaced multiline string, I used this code:

```
output = input.Replace(searchText, replaceText);
```

The problem is that it works only with single line strings (that don't include newlines). How could I make it work for strings that contain newlines?

e.g.

```
searchText = "ABC\nDEF";

replaceText = "text";
```

input:

```
ABC
DEF
KLF
Z
```

output:

```
text
KLF
Z
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  Can you post a [mcve] that demonstrates your current behavior, and then describe the behavior you want?

Comment: i don't understand how the input can be replaced to be the expected output.

Comment: What platform is this on?  Have you tried `\r\n` instead of `\n`?

Comment: The input text is multiline. In that example I'm trying to replace "ABC" followed by "DEF" (they're separated by newline) with "text". How could I do that? (the Replace function to "process" the newline too).

Comment: @Luke Park: Windows 10.

Comment: So did you try with `\r\n`?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to build a search and replace program. input and output are text files, the user writes the searchText and replaceText in 2 separate richTextBoxes. The thing is that I want to make a multiline search and replace.

Comment: Yep, cool, with you up to there, yup.  Did you try with `\r\n`?

Comment: @Luke Park: No. searchText and replaceText are read from 2 richTextBoxes. Should I replace \n from searchText and replaceText with \r\n manually?

Comment: Just look at the answer below, pretty much covers what I was saying.

Answer (score 4):

You need to know what the **new line** is in the input. It could be LF only, but it could be CR+LF.

I am a little bit lazy to explain, so please read this Wikipedia about new line: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

So your problem might be because CR is also there, which makes that the string to search does not match at all. One solution is to set your search text as:

```
searchtext = "ABC" + System.Environment.NewLine + "DEF";
```

System.Environment.NewLine deals with the new line for you better. See the reference in msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Apparently searchText and replaceText which are read from 2 richTextBoxes needed a \r before \n:  searchText = searchText.Replace("\n", "\r\n");  replaceText = replaceText.Replace("\n", "\r\n");